# Programming to supertype in c#

Tags: c#, oop, supertype

I have an OO problem here. I have two sessions which has common properties and specific properties. I created a base class and encapsulated all the common properties/methods.
Two session has a common type called Ranges, which again has common property and specific property for the sessions. Hence I thought I could program to supertype in this case and build the instance at runtime.

```
public class Level
{
    private readonly Ranges _range;

    public Level(Ranges range)
    {
        _range = range;
    }

    public Ranges Range
    {
        get { return _range; }
    }

    public void CommonMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int CommonProperty;
}

public class ALevel : Level
{
    public ALevel()
        : base(new ARange())
    {

    }

    public int ALevelProperty;
}

public class BLevel : Level
{
    public BLevel()
        : base(new BRange())
    {

    }

    public int BLevelProperty;
}

public class Ranges
{
    public int CommonRangeProperty;
}

public class ARange : Ranges
{
    public int ARangeProperty;

    public ARange() 
    {

    }
}

public class BRange : Ranges
{
    public int BRangeProperty;
}

public class ASession
{
    public ASession()
    {
        Level = new ALevel();
    }

    public ALevel Level { get; set; }
}

public class BSession
{
    public BSession()
    {
        Level = new BLevel();
    }

    public BLevel Level { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a session object, it doesn't contain specific Ranges property of ASession.
I can access only the base class's property
    aSession.Level.Range.CommonRangeProperty = 1;
but am not able to access the aSession's specific property
    aSession.Level.Range.ARangeProperty.

Am I doing something wrong in here?

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ASession aSession = new ASession();

        aSession.Level.Range.CommonRangeProperty = 1;
        //Not able to see ARangeProperty

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's pretty simple:

your class `Level` sets the type of `Range` to `Ranges` (not the specific `ARange` nor `BRange`).
you should work with generics, eg:

```
public abstract class Level<TRange>
   where TRange : Ranges
{
    private readonly TRange _range;
    protected Level(TRange range)
    {
        this._range = range;
    }
    public TRange Range
    {
        get
        {
            return this._range;
        }
    }
}

public class ALevel : Level<ARange>
{
    public ALevel()
        : base (new ARange())
    {
    }
}
```

you can take this example even further:

```
public abstract class Level<TRange>
   where TRange : Ranges/*, new()*/ // i'm not sure about the new() ... have no compiler access right now to check!
{
    private readonly TRange _range = new TRange();
    public TRange Range
    {
        get
        {
            return this._range;
        }
    }
}

public class ALevel : Level<ARange>
{
}
```

our you could introduce another member in `ALevel`, like so:

```
public class ALevel : Level
{
   public ARange ARange;
}
```

you could enhance this example by making `Range` in `Level` virtual and overriding `Range` (with a redirect to the concrete `ARange` or `BRange`) in the concrete Levels.

it heavily depends on the usage afterwards...
if you need generic access to the proprety `Range` as `Ranges` you should introduce another base class (without generic constraint) to introduce a base member, which you can override in your generic base class. so you can cast an instance of `ALevel` to `Level` (w/o the base class you would have to cast to `Level<TRange>` which the knowledge of the concrete `TRange`) ...

Comment: Wow! Ur solution was simple yet powerful. Thank you! But can you explain me the problem with code?

Comment: @sundar i've tried to explain that with my first sentence "your class Level sets the type of Range to Ranges (not the specific ARange nor BRange)" - is this point clear?

Comment: but Ranges is the supertype here so I should be able to assign derived type to it.

Comment: @sundar yep ... assigning and accessing are two completely different things (... mainly) ... a variable of type `Ranges` can be assigned any instance of `Ranges`-implementation. but as the type of the variable is `Ranges` the value gets boxed. so you have 2 choices: unboxing (doing a cast), or making the type generic ... is that clear to you? (posted an example @ http://pastebin.com/vCMJiAud)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you need to use generics to do what you are trying to accomplish.  Your code will look something like

```
public class Level<TRange>
    where TRange: Ranges
{
    private readonly TRange _range;

    public TRange Range
    {
        get
        {
            return this._range;
        }
    }
}

public class ALevel : Level<ARange>
{

}
```

The super class will then be able to use Range as the base type and your derived classes will be able to use it as their specific type.

Comment: `ALevel` does not have access to `Level._range` because of `private` visibility. you should at least mark `_range` as protected - or introduce a `protected` get-property